# How we could dockerizing a Proton-Native App and see the GUI?

Tags: react-native, docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, proton-native

I'm trying to dockerize a Proton-Native App, buy i'am not able of see the basic proyect

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN npm install
COPY . ./

RUN npx proton-native-cli init .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then I run

```
docker build -t sample:dev .
```

and

```
docker run sample:dev
```

Assuming that is posible see the GUI, not only access the docker image. What would be the correct way to complete the configuration?

Thanks for read! :)

Comment: I'd suggest that Docker is not at all a good fit for interactive desktop GUI applications (and especially not cluster environments like Kubernetes or Swarm).  You need to do a lot of extra work to get the display to show up at all (including installing extra host software on non-Linux hosts) and even more work to get access to user preferences and data files.  It's much easier to just run this class of program directly on the host, without an isolation layer like Docker involved.

Comment: @Dario Was the above comment helpful to you?

Comment: Yes, it has been useful. The issue is about extra-complexity that brings nothing to development purpouses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea, dockerizing a Proton-Native App for see the gui, is not a simple task, requires "a lot of extra work to get the display to show up at all (including installing extra host software on non-Linux hosts) and even more work to get access to user preferences and data files", like @DavidMaze explains